# Can't log into admin area in magento! Need help quick

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, login

I can't seem to get into the admin area in magento. I think it's a cookie issue as the page is just reloading and I've cleared the cache manually, cleared the cookies in my browser but still I'm locked out. Edited the Varien.php and commented the last 3 lines on the cookie (yes I know your not suppose to edit the core code but I'm at a loss here). I really need to get in to it asap. Can I clear the sessions in the sessions folder and will that help?

Hope someone can help

Comment: try in different browser

Comment: tried incognito mode, tried firefox, safari. It just reloads the login page

Answer (score 2):

You can try by changing value in your **`core_config_data`** table with path **web/unsecure/base_url** and **web/secure/base_url** for localhost to 127.0.0.1

Clean the session folder and cache folder in **/var** directory.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there are a few things you can try:

- change password from admin user through DB
- create a new admin via MySQL and try to login
- clear all caches and tmp/session files and try again
- try a different browser
- try incognito mode from Chrome

Comment: Hi max, I tried using incognito mode it didn't work. Tried using safari with no cookies or browser history and did the same with firefox that also didn't work. Cleared the cache on each attempt to login. I'm at a loss now so I'm willing to pay someone to fix this problem. Anyone knows anyone that can do it for me please let me know as I need this fixing asap.

Comment: What have you done **before** that problem occured?

Comment: editing footer links and the header.phtml in the template file to make the the logo https. and it worked fine after that.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change password with this script https://gist.github.com/litzinger/48be5876d6bba1509323
. You need put this script in root directory and than will call from browser

http://magentoshop.domain/create-magento-user.php. 
Of course change this parameters:

```
define( 'USERNAME', 'new.user' );
define( 'PASSWORD', 'password' );
define( 'FIRSTNAME', 'Excited' );
define( 'LASTNAME', 'Croc' );
define( 'EMAIL', 'new.user@magento.com' );
```